# How to add usercontrols from a static method (in winforms)?

Tags: winforms, user-controls, this, static-methods

I'm trying to create a function that adds usercontrols to my mainform. I want this function to be available from the usercontrols themselves as well, so I'm making it static.

My problem is that when it's static I can't use `this.Controls.Add(ucontrol);`, I tried to change it to `ActiveForm.Controls.Add(ucontrol);` but then ActiveForm is NULL and has no Controls property (throws an exception).

**UPDATE #1:** I ended up doing something like this inside the usercontrol:

```
MainForm ref_to_mainform_to_gain_access_to_functions = (MainForm)Parent;      
ref_to_mainform_to_gain_access_to_functions.DisplayControl(ucontrol);
```

maybe it's even better, but I still assume it's possible to have access to the mainform from a static method?

**UPDATE #2:**

```
Application.OpenForms["FormName"]
```

worked from static method.

I still try to find out if that usercontrol entire purpose is serve as a menu with buttons that shows other usercontrols onclick, is it still a 'design-crime' to call a function on mainform (a function that shows usercontrols) from a user control? (like I did in 'update #1')

Comment: This is one of the ways that Winforms reminds you that you are doing it wrong.  A user control should *never* be in the business of adding controls to its parent.  Raise an event.

Comment: @HansPassant - Could you please explain why is it so wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding controls from a user control to its parent you are breaking the separation of concerns principle and you are tightly coupling both controls/forms. As suggested by Hans Passant you should use events. Please refer to:
[best practices to call methods in the parent form and access gui elements in parent form in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013343/best-practices-to-call-methods-in-the-parent-form-and-access-gui-elements-in-par)

Comment: And in case that the usercontrol's entire purpose is to serve as a menu with buttons that shows other usercontrols onclick, is it still a 'design-crime' to call a function on mainform (a function that shows usercontrols) from a user control? (like I did in 'update #1')

Comment: Yes. What you are doing is tightly coupling both controls. It means that neither of the controls can be used on its own and they can only be used together. You might very well merge those two controls in a single control and the outcome would be the same. There is a lot of good materials on the internet about creating loosely coupled components and separation of concerns. I highly advise you do a little research and investigate those concepts.